# How does calling ReactDOM.render multiple times instantiate a component only once?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a function that renders an alert component whenever I click a button in the root node,
and the behaviour is that when I dismiss the alert it should return null, thus removing it to the mountNode which I have checked, and it does. However, as I have click the button again, it does not seem to render, instantiate for that matter. How come?

```
function buttonHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ReactDOM.render(
        <CustomAlert/>,
        document.getElementById(mountNode)
    );
}
```

the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';


export default class CustomAlert extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: true 
        }
        this.handleAlertDismiss = this.handleAlertDismiss.bind(this);
    }

    handleAlertDismiss() {
        this.setState({ show: false });
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.show) {
            return (
                <Alert bsStyle="danger" onDismiss={this.handleAlertDismiss}>
                    <h4> Test </h4>
                </Alert>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make it even easier for someone to help you by making your example a runnable [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I don't see any code setting the state to `show: true`...perhaps you need to be passing that as a prop to your component, and setting the state in the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook.

Comment: @Ted I've just tried it and it worked. So basically calling ReactDOM.render does not instantiate the component every time?

Comment: @HeanzyZabala exactly. If the component has been instantiated, and not removed, all render does is update it--or check to see if it needs updating.

Comment: @Ted so returning null does not mean it destroy the component even though its been removed from the hierarchy. thanks